# How to do longtext with code first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to generate `longtext` type database column using an Entity Framework code-first approach. I already used `Column(TypeName = "longtext")` data annotation but I am getting error

> Column, parameter, or variable #3: Cannot find data type LONGTEXT.

My code:

```
public class MyText
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "longtext")]
    public string Txt { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea how I can generate a `longtext` column then?

Comment: what db are u using?

Comment: _Cannot find data type LONGTEXT_ means that there is no `longtext` data type in your provider (for example, there is no longtext in [MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings)). Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried putting [Column(TypeName = "ntext")] on the string property?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell db name. is it MS SQL server and project is .net core 2.1 MVC type

Comment: there is no such data type in sql server.  if you leave a string property without any string length attribute the code first generation will script the schema as nvarchar(max)

Comment: Ok. Then tell me how can i do this `max` from code first approach?

Comment: @vasily.sib - yip corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you go - pretty straight forward...

```
public class MyText
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //leaving this blank it will give you nvarchar(MAX)
    public string Txt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i'd be cautious about having too many nvarchar(max) cols in one table...use sparingly

Comment: Yes this was the fix for here. Thanks bro. This simple answer gets too long on stackoverfollow. haha